# Javascript - Error in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

The below code keeps on spewing out this error. I can't work out why.

Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
jQuery(function($) {
var eventMethod, eventer, frame, messageEvent;
frame = $("#cf-iframe");
alert(frame.length);
if (frame.length > 0) {
  console.log("somehow");
  eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  eventer = window[eventMethod];
  messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
  return eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    var newHeight;
    newHeight = e.data;
    if (!isNaN(newHeight && frame === true)) {
      return frame.css("height", newHeight + "px");
    }
  }, false);
}
});

}).call(this);
```

Comment: cant see any "state" in the code i think its half of the code!!

Comment: I think that it is coming from elsewhere. It would make sense. This code looks good to me.

Comment: @NeelBhatt I agree with you, there's no reference to a state var in the code pasted here

Comment: Maybe you should try this on in cognito - (without any of the browser plugins/addons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK, but seem's that the error is from otside...

Check your script

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "onmessage" and "message" are skipped in your code. I    tried this on chrome. and it doesnt error out. You also don't need the '$' in `jQuery(function($))`.

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    var eventMethod, eventer, frame, messageEvent;
    frame = $("#cf-iframe");

    if (frame.length > 0) {

      eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

      eventer = window[eventMethod];

      messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent" ? "message" : "onmessage";

      return eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
        var newHeight;
        newHeight = e.data;
        if (!isNaN(newHeight && frame === true)) {
          return frame.css("height", newHeight + "px");
        }
      }, false);
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```